# HAXM not working on Linux

Tags: android, android-emulator, haxm

Here we go for `GingerBread`:

> http://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2012/03/12/how-to-start-intel-hardware-assistedvirtualization-hypervisor-on-linux-to-speed-up-intel-android-x86-gingerbread-emulator/

Any updates for `ICECream sandwich` or `Kitkat`? Helpful answers are highly appreciated!!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

HAXM is only needed on Windows and OS X. On Linux, you need to have KVM installed.

See the "Configuring VM Acceleration on Linux" section on:
https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-acceleration#vm-linux

Just download x86 based system images in the SDK Manager, then start the AVD, KVM will be auto-detected and used automatically if your machine/system supports it.

Answer (score 7):

As already mentioned by @Digit, you do not need HAXM on Linux but KVM.

Although the links in the other answers give a comprehensive answer, for those who like it short, on my Ubuntu, this was just enough:

```
sudo apt-get install kvm
```

Comment: Don't forget `sudo usermod -aG kvm $USER`, then you must log out and back in.

Answer (score 5):

KVM has to be enabled by inserting the kernel module:

```
sudo modprobe kvm-intel
```

[How to Start Intel Hardware-assisted Virtualization (hypervisor) on Linux to Speed-up Intel Android x86 Emulator](https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2012/03/12/how-to-start-intel-hardware-assisted-virtualization-hypervisor-on-linux-to-speed-up-intel-android-x86-emulator) might help; verbose output is also useful for testing:

```
emulator -avd ... -verbose
```

should log something like:

```
emulator: CPU Acceleration: working
emulator: CPU Acceleration status: KVM (version 12) is installed and usable.
```

the [qemuhowto](http://www.android-x86.org/documents/qemuhowto) states:

> You must have kvm module (kvm-intel or kvm-amd) installed for your kernel, and the permission of /dev/kvm is set to allow your user to access it. Otherwise the KVM support will be disabled and it may run very slow.

Answer (score 4):

here is step by step how to get KVM Installation with images
[How to Start Intel Hardware-assisted Virtualization (hypervisor) on Linux to Speed-up Intel Android x86 Emulator](https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2012/03/12/how-to-start-intel-hardware-assisted-virtualization-hypervisor-on-linux-to-speed-up-intel-android-x86-emulator)

Answer (score 3):

The Intel Hardware Accelerated Execution Manager provides hardware-assisted virtualization. It should (hopefully) work the same with more recent versions of the Android emulator. Use the Android SDK Manager to download the KitKat x86 emulator.

Here's a more recent Intel document: http://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/speeding-up-the-android-emulator-on-intel-architecture
and Google's documentation: http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html

Do follow those instructions.

If it still doesn't work for you, there are many possible causes such as: not having an Intel CPU, not installed properly, need to set BIOS settings, need to reboot, need to allocate lots of memory to HAXM, need to keep the AVD memory size down, attempting to configure the emulator to use the host GPU, ...

What are the specific symptoms? Do try searching for them on Google.

Also search for [Hardware Accelerated Execution Manager linux](https://www.google.com/search?q=Hardware%20Accelerated%20Execution%20Manager%20linux) for more documentation and experience reports.