# Android Studio AVD doesn't start

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

When i run a x86 emulator, it won't start. I tried run this command on terminal:

```
/home/username/Android/Sdk/tools/emulator -avd Nexus_5X_API_26 -netspeed full
```

and ı got this output: emulator: WARNING: Not all modern X86 virtualization features supported, which introduces problems with slowdown when running Android on  multicore vCPUs. Setting AVD to run with 1 vCPU core only.

arm emulators run but x86 emulators don't.

My os: Debian 9

Answer (score 0):

First of all check your code for errors if everything ok

Second check that you have intel haxm installed and working

I hope that I have helped you

Comment: How can I install haxm on debian I couldn't find anything.

Comment: Sorry I thought your using Windows check this that might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22216708/haxm-not-working-on-linux